# Is var.append() in Python same as array_push in PHP

Tags: python

I tried searching for this and found that var.append() is similar to array_push but it never worked for me.

My Py code:

```
file_name = input('Enter a file name: ')
f = open(file_name, 'r')
data = f.readlines()
result = []
for line in data:
      values = line.split()
      print(values)

      read_line = dict({
                'vertex': values[0],
                'visited': values[1],
                'letter': values[2],
                'neighbors': values[3]
                })
      result.append(read_line)
      break
      print(result)
```

I am trying to append read_line to result and print result outside the loop but it is only printing the first read line. However the same code is working for me in PHP when i use array_push.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Maybe incorrect indentation?

Comment: You're breaking out of the loop, so it only runs once.

Comment: Also, you don't need `dict()` around a dictionary literal. Just use the curly braces. You can also just do `for line in f` instead of creating `data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `break` and put `print(result)` outside of the loop.

Comment: Break is used for ending the loop, No?

Comment: If you end it, it will run only once, consequently, you will append only once...

Comment: Oh hate random forums posting incorrect information. Thanks for help :)

Comment: provide a url, let me see what they wrote.

Comment: I am sorry, i cant find it any more :S